# Django error: Relation "<name>" already exists

Tags: python, django, django-models, migration, django-simple-history

I am attempting to run migrations on an existing model where i am adding a history field/table via the [django-simple-history](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html). I initially ran made and ran the migrations and then ran `python manage.py populate_history --auto` to generate the initial change for the pre-existing model. This created a new table in the DB and now when i try and re-run migrations, i get the error that `relation <name> already exists`. Do i have to delete/drop the table for the db?

Comment: Which relation `<name>` was mentioned? It may be important.

Comment: @SUTerliakov It's a relation i already created that it's attempting to recreate. The name isnt relevant. Problem is, i dont know why it's trying to re-create the relation nor how to stop it from doing so, or how to get around this issue.